# How does "read" instruction works without arguments?

Tags: bash, shell

I try to get dovecot mailbox size by this command `doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com` which gives me this table:

```
Quota name  Type    Value   Limit   %
User quota  STORAGE 627367  104857600   0
User quota  MESSAGE 3217    -   0
```

I need to extract 627367 value. So I tried to use standard method:

```
$ doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com | while read 
> do 
>     COL3=`awk '{print $3}'`
>     COL4=`awk '{print $4}'`
> done
```

COL3 and COL4 should give me description of value and value. I need to find out whether "COL3 == 'STORAGE'" and if yes echo COL4. Later I've noticed that `while read` without variable gives me data without header:

```
$ doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com | while read 
> do 
>         cat
> done

User quota  STORAGE 627367  104857600   0
User quota  MESSAGE 3217    -   0
```

I found it interesting because I don't need to recognize header and I could analyze useful data. But it seemed not very easy. If I insert `echo` it says me that `while` run three times:

```
$ doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com | while read 
> do 
>         echo "Test"
> done

Test
Test
Test
```

With `awk` `while` runs two times:

```
$ doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com | while read 
> do 
>         awk '{print $3}'
> done

STORAGE
MESSAGE
```

But when I start to parse result I found that `while` runs only one time:

```
$ doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com | while read 
> do 
>         COL3=`awk '{print $3}'`
>         echo $COL3
> done

STORAGE MESSAGE
```

So when I try to use

```
if [ "$COL3" == "STORAGE" ]
then
    echo "Test"
fi
```

it never works. I tried to compare with "MESSAGE" and even with "STORAGE MESSAGE". It not works.

I didn't find any information what `read` do without any arguments. And I want to ask, have I use standard method and parse all lines including header or I can use `read` without arguments and try to parse getting data? And how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question,

```
doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com | awk -- '/STORAGE/ { print $4 }'
```

The `awk` pattern `/STORAGE/` selects the line that contains `STORAGE`, and then the `print` prints the number you want.

As far as `read` in general, see [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read).  `read` without parameters puts the entire line into `$REPLY`, so you shouldn't access standard input otherwise.  Using `awk` within your `read` loop means that `read` doesn't get to see every line, because `read` takes lines and `awk` also takes lines.

Comment: Thank you very much! Two answers and both helped me! First helped to solve my problem with awk, second helped to to satisfy curiosity about `read` behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

as pointed by @cxw, `while` without parameters puts the entire line into `$REPLY`

So you should write

```
while read
do
  echo "$REPLY" | awk '/STORAGE/ { print $4 }'
done < <(doveadm -f tab quota get -u test@example.com)
```

Comment: Or, even tighter, `awk '/STORAGE/ { print $4 }' <<<"$REPLY"` :)

Comment: @cxw tighter is the cream

Comment: I tried this way but I think `read` with arguments or @cxw variant is more purer.